# Async await call request.user in Django 4.1 causes SynchronousOnlyOperation

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using this async code to check user is is_authenticated:

```
async def offers(request, currency_id):
    user = await User.objects.aget(pk=request.user.pk)
    currency = await sync_to_async(get_object_or_404)(Currency, pk=currency_id)
    offers_to_sell = [
        item
        async for item in Offer.objects.filter(
            currency_to_sell_id=currency_id
        ).prefetch_related("currency_to_sell", "currency_to_buy")
    ]
    context = {"currency": currency, "offers_to_sell": offers_to_sell, "user": user}
    return render(request, template_name="offers.html", context=context)
```

But it throws me an error:

```
SynchronousOnlyOperation 
You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 187, in _get_session
    return self._session_cache
```

Also I tried this code, but with no luck:

```
user = await sync_to_async(User.objects.get)(pk=request.user.pk)
```

And from template without using code in view:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

But result is the same.

It looks that there is something I missed about async call.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed this myself, I managed to get around it by accessing it like this:

```
@sync_to_async
def get_user_from_request(request: HttpRequest) -> User | AnonymousUser | None:
    return request.user if bool(request.user) else None
```

And calling this in the view

```
async def api_view(request: HttpRequest) -> None:
    user = await get_user_from_request(request)
```

Seems like others have been experiencing the same for a while https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31920, and that solutions are being looked into e.g.: `user = await request.auser()`